# Find $P(X<2Y)$ of a bivariate distribution

Tags: self-study, density-function

$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2 \pi }\exp(-\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}})$ where
$x,y$ in $\Bbb R$

My attempt: 
$$\Bbb P(X<2Y) =
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{2y}\frac{1}{2 \pi }\exp(-\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}})\text{d}x\text{d}y =
2\int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{2 \pi }\frac{-\sqrt{5}}{2} \exp(-\sqrt{5}y) \text{d}y$$

The answer I get is $\frac{-1}{2\pi}$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It would be nice for you to provide more detail about how you get from the second expression to the third (I get that you integrated out and used symmetry to simplify the second integral, but it would be good to list out step by step what you did). Also, there is a much more elegant solution than this brute force integral that exploits the rotational symmetry of $f(x,y)$. Unless you are required to use the brute force method, I would recommend trying to find a more elegant derivation.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming here that by $\sqrt(x^2 + y^2)$, you really mean $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. If that's the case, you should really be doing "\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}" with braces instead of parentheses in your TeX. Otherwise, forget what I said about spherical symmetry.

Comment: (+1) to @stats_model for suggesting a change of variables to polar coordinates.

Comment: Drawing a picture will *immediately* show you the answer with no calculation at all, because it will become apparent that (1) the distribution is centrally symmetric and (2) the plane is the disjoint union of the half plane determined by $x\lt 2y,$ its symmetric image $-x\lt -2y,$ and the line (of zero probability) $x=y.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$P(X<2Y)=\Bbb P(X<2Y) =
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{2y}\frac{1}{2 \pi }\exp(-\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}})\text{d}x\text{d}y $$

$x=r \cos(\theta) $ $y=r \sin(\theta) $ $\quad r>0$

$$=\int_{\theta \in (\tan^{-1}.5,\pi +\tan^{-1}.5)}\int_{r \in (0,\infty)} \frac{1}{2 \pi }e^{-\sqrt{r^2}} r\ dr\ d\theta $$

[image]

$$=\int_{\theta \in (\tan^{-1}.5,\pi +\tan^{-1}.5)}\int_{r \in (0,\infty)} \frac{1}{2 \pi }\ r e^{-r}  dr\ d\theta $$

$$=\int_{r \in (0,\infty)} \frac{1}{2  }\ r e^{-r}  dr\ $$

another method

hint

$f(-x,y)=f(x,y)=f(x,-y)=f(-x,-y)$

symmetric +continues

$P(X<2Y)=P(Y<2X)$

since $(X,Y)\sim (-X, -Y)$

$$P(X<2Y)\overset{(X,Y)\sim (-X, -Y)}{=}P(-X<-2Y)=P(X>2Y)$$